# How to Pass by default anchor tag style of BootStrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to ignore default `<a></a>` tag of bootstrap (dark sky color) to make my text appear as normal.

My text is wrapped by `<a>` tag and `<span>` tag, therefore the default style of `<a>` tag is applied as default.

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="text-bg"><strong>0</strong></span><br>
    <span class="text-xs">NEW(999)</span>
</a>
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
    <span class="text-bg"><strong>0</strong></span><br>
    <span class="text-xs">NEW(999)</span>
</a>
```

I understand that set manually set style would be fine, however, it would be less painful to pass by `<a>` tag style and get the normal text color (gray color) instead.

Is there any way I could achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a pic of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Well then use `inherit` ...? Or customize your bootstrap instance according to your wishes, by setting the relevant variable(s). https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#scaffolding

Comment: @CBroe, setting style to instance directly would be fine, however, I would like to know if there is any other easier way just to skip the style, `a` style. Thanks.

Comment: Now, you can not "skip" styles. You need to overwrite or at least unset them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strictly overwrite the user agent stylesheet at once.
This Could be the solution. See the Example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link !important;
    cursor: auto !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
a{
    color: -webkit-link !important;
    cursor: auto !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
</style>  
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">
    <span class="text-bg"><strong>0</strong></span><br>
    <span class="text-xs">NEW(999)</span>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. However, I would like my text to get normal text style of bootstrap which is gray color. Therefore, I would like to skip `a` style of bootstrap including its underline style.

Comment: Your Welcome! You can also remove style of <a> tag from bootstrap.css. This solution works only when you want your <a> tag has same style (Default) for whole page.

Comment: Thanks. Not every `a` link I would like it to appear as gray as default normal in bootstrap.

Comment: Ok, So you may apply this solution and can also apply media queries for diff. browser. :)

Comment: It seem more work to do than I expected above. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: BDW, if you work more for this then you may not need to ask here. :)